# After upgrading AS, new resourses fails to reflect changes in the editor

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-resources

Since I separate many resources files to free and pro version folders (different builds variants), specially string.xml and layouts, time to time adding new strings, ID does not reflects immediately in the code showing the typical “Cannot resolve symbol”. The interesting part is that running the code, everything works okay; it’s just the annoying red error lines in code.

- This phenomenon occurs after upgrading to Android Studio 3.6.1.
- It ocurrs switching from one build variant to another randomly during coding.
- Invalidate and Restart it’s a temporary solution, but the problem reappears after a while.
- Restarting the Project does the same, but is faster.

Example:
This is a new added string resource

```
<string name="m_example">This is an example resource in string.xml</string>
```

After gradle sync, in the editor:

[image]

If anybody knows how to fix this, I will appreciate very much, because it causes headaches. In the meanwhile I stuck restarting AS. Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you try Build -> Clean Project then Build -> Rebuild Project (optional)

Comment: @BurhanKhanzada yes, everytime.